# Boost::Geometry - Find area of 2d polygon in 3d space?

Tags: c++, area, boost-geometry

I'm trying to get area of 2d polygon in 3d space. Is there any way to do this by Boost::Geometry? Here is my implementation, but it returns 0 all the time:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 3, bg::cs::cartesian> point3d;

int main()
{
    bg::model::multi_point<point3d> square;
    bg::read_wkt("MULTIPOINT((0 0 0), (0 2 0), (0 2 2), (0 0 2), (0 0 0))", square);
    double area = bg::area(square);
    std::cout << "Area: " << area << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

*UPD*: Actually, I have the same issue with the simple 2d multi point square:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point2d;

int main()
{
    bg::model::multi_point<point2d> square;
    bg::read_wkt("MULTIPOINT((0 0), (2 0), (2 2), (0 2))", square);
    double area = bg::area(square);
    std::cout << "Area: " << area << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result:

```
$ ./test_area
Area: 0
```

**UPD**: Looks like area calculation in the `boost::geometry` availabe only for the 2 dimensional polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't expect a collection of points to have an area. You would need the equivalent of a `model::polygon<poind3d>` but that does not appear to be supported at the moment.

If the points are guaranteed to be co-planar and the segment do not intersect each other, you could decompose the polygons as a series of triangles and compute the area with a little bit of linear-algebra, based on the following formula for the area of a triangle:
[image]

In case of non-convex polygons, the sum of the areas need to be adapted to subtract areas outside the polygon. The easiest way to achieve this is by using signed areas for the triangles, including positive contributions from right-hand triangles, and negative contributions from left-hand triangles:
[image]

Note that there seems to be some plans to include a `cross_product` implementation in Boost, but it doesn't appear to be included as of version 1.56. The following replacement should do the trick for your use-case:

```
point3d cross_product(const point3d& p1, const point3d& p2)
{
  double x = bg::get<0>(p1);
  double y = bg::get<1>(p1);
  double z = bg::get<2>(p1);
  double u = bg::get<0>(p2);
  double v = bg::get<1>(p2);
  double w = bg::get<2>(p2);
  return point3d(y*w-z*v, z*u-x*w, x*v-y*u);
}
point3d cross_product(const bg::model::segment<point3d>& p1
                    , const bg::model::segment<point3d>& p2)
{
  point3d v1(p1.second);
  point3d v2(p2.second);
  bg::subtract_point(v1, p1.first);
  bg::subtract_point(v2, p2.first);

  return cross_product(v1, v2);
}
```

The area can then be computed with something such as:

```
// compute the are of a collection of 3D points interpreted as a 3D polygon
// Note that there are no checks as to whether or not the points are
// indeed co-planar.
double area(bg::model::multi_point<point3d>& polygon)
{
  if (polygon.size()<3) return 0;

  bg::model::segment<point3d> v1(polygon[1], polygon[0]);
  bg::model::segment<point3d> v2(polygon[2], polygon[0]);
  // Compute the cross product for the first pair of points, to handle
  // shapes that are not convex.
  point3d n1 = cross_product(v1, v2);
  double normSquared = bg::dot_product(n1, n1);
  if (normSquared > 0)
  {
    bg::multiply_value(n1, 1.0/sqrt(normSquared));
  }
  // sum signed areas of triangles
  double result = 0.0;
  for (size_t i=1; i<polygon.size(); ++i)
  {
    bg::model::segment<point3d> v1(polygon[0], polygon[i-1]);
    bg::model::segment<point3d> v2(polygon[0], polygon[i]);

    result += bg::dot_product(cross_product(v1, v2), n1);
  }
  result *= 0.5;
  return abs(result);
}
```

Comment: You missed the last term in cross product summation, it needs to end where it started from.

Comment: @Mrigank The tests I ran gave me the expected result. Do you have specific test cases which do not yield the correct result?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the geometry section of boost, but with my knowledge of geometry, I can say that it would not be much different in 3D than 2D.  Although there might be something in boost already, You could write your own method that does this fairly easily.

EDIT:

da code monkey pointed out that the [shoelace formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) would be more efficient in this way, because it is less complicated, and faster.

Original Idea below:

---

To calculate this, I would first tessellate the polygon into triangles, because any polygon can be split up into a number of triangles.  I would take each of these triangles, and calculate the area of each of them.  To do this in 3d space, the same concepts apply.  To get the base, you take △ABC and arbitrarily assign —AB as base, —BC as height, and —CA as hypotenuse.  Just do (—AB*—BC)/2  .  Just add up the areas of each triangle.

I do not know if boost has a built in tessellate method, and this would be fairly difficult to implement in c++, but you would probably want to create a triangle fan of some sort. (NOTE: this only applies to convex polygons).  If you do have a concave polygon, you should look into this: http://www.cs.unc.edu/~dm/CODE/GEM/chapter.html  I will leave putting this into c++ as an exercise, but the process is fairly simple.

Comment: any reasonably simple triangulation algorithm is going to take n log n time.  I would recommend the simpler shoelace formula, which is linear.

Comment: I believe the OP was asking for a solution in 3D space, whereas the shoelace formula is for polygons in 2D space. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25349884/2994596) for a generalization to 3D space (which simplifies to the shoelace formula when the the points are in the xy plane).

Comment: i guess the shoelace formula is more for 2d space (although There might be a 3d variant), but my original idea would still work.